# custom exception message in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Im trying to raise a custom exception message when I get an exception but I get the following error -

```
try:
   query_start_time = time.time()
   execute_sql_alchemy_query

except Exception as ex:
    elapsed_time = (time.time() - query_start_time)/60
    print(type(ex))
    raise type(ex)("Query elapsed time(in mins) - {0}".format(elapsed_time))
```

Error:-

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/profiles/sources/impact/test.py", line 110, in _handle_future_exception
    future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 428, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'params' and 'orig'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception being raised is probably a subclass of DBAPIError (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError) which takes 3 positional/mandatory parameters in its constructor (statement, params and orig), by trying to raise it like this, you are only providing a “statement” but not the 2 other arguments.

You could probably manage to make it work by providing the .params and .orig from the initial exception but I’d discourage you to go that way because it’s error prone and a bit fragile (it will break if the exception is not a DBAPIError), instead I’d suggest to simply log the time separately from the error (using logging.warning)